# Prove that if $g^{n} \in H$, $n$ divides $|g|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let H be a subgroup of a finite group $G$. Suppose that $g$ belongs to $G$ and $n$ is the smallest positive integer such that $g^{n} \in H$. Prove that $n$ divides |g|.

I couldn't get anywhere with this problem due to the condition "$n$ is the smallest positive integer such that $g^{n} \in H$." I tried letting $|g|=m$, then I could show $a^{m-n}\in H$. I also realized $a^{kn} \in H\ (k\in N^{+})$ as well, since $H$ contains the identity element. But how do these things lead to anywhere?

Comment: If you showed $a^{m-n}\in H$, you can show $a^{m-2n}\in H$, and $a^{m-3n}\in H$, etc. How far can this go?

Comment: It can go up to $a^{m-(m-1)n}=a^{n} \in H$ since both are inverse elements of $a^{-n}$. But how does this imply $m-(m-1)n$ is divisible by $n$, or m is divisible by n?

Comment: Consider only positive powers of $a$ that belong to $H$. You know $a^m$ does, and $n$ is the smallest positive power. You can show $a^{m-qn}$ belongs to $H$ for any integer $q$. How small a positive integer can you make $m-qn$ be?

Comment: Thank you for your great hint! m-qn = n, which implies n divides m. Is that right?

Comment: Well, more or less. You need to use division to write $m=nq+r$ where $0\leq r<n$. Then $a^{m-nq}=a^r \in H$. However $r<n$, and $n$ was the smallest positive integer with that property. Therefore $r=0$, and $m=nq$.

Comment: Many thanks for your help!

Comment: This is exercise 45 in chapter 3 of Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra.

Comment: Hi! I'm struggling with this problem, too, and I am very lost. How were you able to show that, in general, $g^{m - qn} \in H$?

Answer (score 5):

If $n$ didn't divide $|g|$ then $|g| = nq + r$ for some $q \in \mathbb{N}$ and $r \in (0,n)$. Since $e=g^{|g|} = g^{nq}g^{r}$, derive a contradiction with the minimality of $n$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think it is the same solution by Prometheus:)

Answer (score 2):

Another proof is as follows. If $G$ is finite then $|g|$ is finite. Allow $|g|=l$. Since $H$ is a group closed under a binary operation within it's own right then $\langle g^n \rangle \leq H$. Notice for any natural number $n$ there must exist some least such natural number $k$ that satisfies $g^{nk}=e$. If there was not, then $|g^n|$ would be an infinite subgroup within $H$, which is a contradiction since the order of $H$ is finite. Thus one can conclude $e=g^{nk}=g^{l}$ and $nk=l$. Dividing both sides by $n$ gives $k=\frac{l}{n}$ which implies that $n| [l=|g|]$  $\square$